# Find points on curve $y = (x^2 - 1)^3 / (x^2 + 1)^3$ when slope of tangent line is zero?

Tags: calculus

As soon as a get to the quotient rule I can't simplify to solve for $x$.

This is what I have tried:

Since the derivative much be equal to zero:

$$0 = [6x(x^2 -1)^2 (x^2+1)^3] - [6x(x^2 + 1)^2(x^2-1)^3]$$

How do I simplify further and solve for $x$?

Answer (score 2):

Note that there is a common term $6x$, of $(x^2 - 1)^2$ and a common term of $(x^2 + 1)^2$, so your equation can be rewritten as

$$0 = 6x (x^2 - 1)^2 (x^2 + 1)^2 \Big((x^2 + 1) - (x^2 - 1)\Big) = 12x (x^2 - 1)^2(x^2 + 1)^2$$

Now set each term to $0$ individually.

Comment: I would use "factor" instead of "term", but +1 anyway :)

Comment: I dont understand how you got 12x, and how ((x^2 + 1) - (x^2-1)) was cancelled out of the equation. Could you please explain?

Comment: @Jesse, just simplify $(x^2+1)-(x^2-1)$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$\displaystyle \frac{d\left(\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}\right)^3}{dx} =\frac{d\left(\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}\right)^3}{d\left(\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}\right)}\cdot\frac{d\left(\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}\right)}{dx}$$

Now, $$\frac{d\left(\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}\right)^3}{d\left(\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}\right)}=3\left(\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}\right)^2$$

and $$\frac{d\left(\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}\right)}{dx}=\frac{d\left(1-\frac2{x^2+1}\right)}{dx}=\frac{2\cdot2x}{(x^2+1)^2}$$